# How to remove namespace from a tag but leave its prefix?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I am able to generate a SOAP message but I do not know

- add prefix only to soapMessage tag (should not have namespace)

  ```
   SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory =
                  SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
   SOAPConnection connection =
                  soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
   SOAPFactory soapFactory =
                  SOAPFactory.newInstance();

   MessageFactory factory =
                  MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);

   SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage();
   SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
   SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
   SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();                
   SOAPBody body = soapEnvelope.getBody();

   soapEnvelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(soapEnvelope.getPrefix());
   soapEnvelope.setPrefix("soap");
   body.setPrefix("soap");

   header.removeNamespaceDeclaration(header.getPrefix());
   header.setPrefix("soap");

   soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("v9", "URL TO SERVER");

   Name bodyName;
   bodyName = soapFactory.createName("SearchHotels");
   SOAPBodyElement getList = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
   getList.setPrefix("v9");

   Name childName = soapFactory.createName("SoapMessage", "v9", "URL TO SERVER");
   SOAPElement HotelListRequest = getList.addChildElement(childName);

   HotelListRequest.addChildElement("Hotel", "v9").addTextNode("Hilton");
  ```

**My SOAP Message**

```
   ...
     <v9:SoapMessage xmlns:els="URL TO SERVER">
         ...
```

**What I expect**

```
   ...
      <v9:SoapMessage>
           ...
```

**Update :**

If I use the following it runs into following error

```
    SOAPElement HotelListRequest = getList.addChildElement("v9:SoapMessage");

    org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a 
                                             way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
```

Comment: I am not sure for the empty header, but the from a semantical perspective both messages equal. The XML producer is allowed to make a late or just-in-time declaration of the namespace. Any parser should be able to live with both versions.

Comment: @mwhs thanks, I could complete the last question but not the rest

Comment: What do you mean not the rest?

Comment: @mwhs I mean how to add header to it, add namespace to all tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the namespace prefix to all the tags you have to redeclare the desired prefix (and eventually the namespace) on **every** inserted child, otherwise it will inherit the namespace (implicitely) from the parent element.

Try for instance:

```
SOAPBodyElement getList = body.addBodyElement(bodyName, "v9", "http://URL TO SERVER");
```

or

```
soapBody.addChildElement("SomeElement", "v9", "http://URL TO SERVER");
```

or

```
soapBody.addChildElement("v9:SomeElement");
```

Sometimes you may have to use a `QName` object instead of just a `String` or a `Name`.

It pretty much depends on the SOAP-API/Implementation you use, but the principle is the same everywhere: either redeclare (explicit) or inherit (implicit).

Comment: Maybe use the method addHeader of the SOAPEnvelope object?

Comment: I've used that before but accidentally removed it :(

Comment: thanks, I could change it, the only thing that I need is to add prefix to the following SoapMessage tag I would appreciate it if you could help me,                                                Name bodyName;
            bodyName = soapFactory.createName("SearchHotels");
           
            SOAPBodyElement getList =
                    body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
            getList.setPrefix("v9");
            
            
            Name childName = soapFactory.createName("SoapMessage");
            SOAPElement HotelListRequest = getList.addChildElement(childName);

Comment: Use the version of createName which offers you to also pass a NS-prefix and the corresponding NS. See this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFactory.html#createName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I've found that as well but the problem is that I do not want it to add namespace url, just need to have the prefix

Comment: once bounty is completed, please remind me to give you a bounty, for your help so far.

Comment: Ok, then you have to create the name like this: `soapBody.addChildElement("v9:SomeElement");` (answer updated)

Comment: Did you declare the els namespace before?

Comment: not sure what you mean by declaring, I just used the addnamespaceDeclaration for soapbody and updated the question with my latest code

Comment: Something like this: `soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("els", "Namspace-URI");`?

Comment: yes I have it as you see in the question. soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("v9", "URL TO SERVER");

Comment: In the question I only see "v9".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40819/discussion-between-alex-and-mwhs)

Comment: I need to wait 23 hours to award the bounty :D I have a new question please have a look at it thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953829/why-am-i-receiving-java-lang-nullpointerexception-rather-than-soap-response

Answer (score -1):

In your expected SOAP message there is a difference in case of prefix , seems you are writing client where requesting to a service provider which is developed in .net , this is why you may need to change prefix .

I think you can take concept from bellow code :

```
       MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL); 
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(); 

    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart(); 

    SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope(); 

    SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody(); 

    soapEnvelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(soapEnvelope.getPrefix()); 
    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"); 

    soapEnvelope.setPrefix("soap"); 
    soapBody.setPrefix("soap"); 

    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); 
    soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");   soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().detachNode(); 

    soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().setHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.example.com/TransactionProcess");
```

For more detail please visit this [REFERENCE LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html)

Comment: thanks , but could not figure out how to add the prefix to the tags, the one that you mention does not work, also now sure how to remove schemas..... namespace and also remove the namespace of searchHotels tag

Comment: @Alex please check the reference link there u will find the solution i checked just now

Comment: i also face some integration problem while trying to write client for different payment gateway , where three way communication was involved - our system, gateway , and another thirdparty system of client -- in three case we had to sync the transaction information with retaining security and integrity , good luck

Comment: thanks, but it is not about three way communication, I need to know how to add header to it, add namespace to all tags

Comment: if u want to build <xs:tag> in body section with prefix and namespace , you can use manual process using StringBuilder -- though may be this is a temporary solution as i think ,